# Calculating second order derivative from timeseries using Pandas .diff()

Tags: python, pandas, difference, derivative, differentiation

An example of my Pandas dataframe is below, with dates as index:

```
            A
2019-01-09  1.007042
2019-01-10  1.007465
2019-01-11  1.007054
2019-01-12  1.007154
2019-01-13  1.007854
2019-01-14  1.008560
```

I'd like to determine the second order derivative every 2 rows of column A. Would it be appropriate to use the `.diff()` function in Pandas twice for this determination?

```
df['A2'] = df['A'].diff(2).diff(2)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a nine month old question, but still appears at the top of google searches for this material and so warrants an acceptable answer. If this disclaimer is unnecessary, I hope someone will remove it for me.

The second derivative can be calculated either as a central, forward or backward derivative, but based off your example, I think you're looking for the backward derivative. It can be calculated on every row if you want, however, it could be really hard to do with `diff()`. The function `shift()` works well though and the method is as follows:

```py
df['A2'] = df['A'] - 2*df['A'].shift(1) + df['A'].shift(2)
```

the technique relies on [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference)

Comment: Note that if the index has a dimension this will not return the correct value for the derivative, you would have to divide by the unit shift squared (see h**2 in the second order backwards equation on the wikipedia link)

Comment: Just to add to @Dan White's answer:  `df['A2'] = (df['A'] - 2*df['A'].shift(h) + df['A'].shift(2h)) / h^2` where h is the spacing between data point, chosen as h=1 here for simplicity.

Answer (score 2):

For the differences between your differences, call [`pd.Series.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.diff.html) twice.

```
df['A2'] = df['A'].diff().diff()

print(df)

                   A        A2
2019-01-09  1.007042       NaN
2019-01-10  1.007465       NaN
2019-01-11  1.007054 -0.000834
2019-01-12  1.007154  0.000511
2019-01-13  1.007854  0.000600
2019-01-14  1.008560  0.000006
```

The argument to `pd.Series.diff` is **periods**, so `pd.Series.diff(2)` returns differences between a value and a value 2 rows away. But this isn't what you want here.

Comment: yes the argument it periods, but if I want the 2nd derivative between rows `n` and `n-2`, wouldn't it be `.diff(2).diff(2)`?

Comment: @pepe, "Second derivative" is used to signify "change in change", not "differences skipping *n* values".

Comment: i know, but my point is that i do not want to compare values in two adjacent rows—I want to compare the 2nd derivative between alternate rows—not sure if this is clear

Comment: So what you've defined is **not** "second order derivative". If you have a new question, or need to clarify your question, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54505175/edit). Remember, SO is a resource primarily for thousands of other visitors. Anyone looking for "second order derivative" *shouldn't* want differences skipping *n* values. If you edit your question to clarify (both title and content), I'll delete this answer, and you can start again.

Comment: I don't follow—if one has data obtained every 15 min, a second derivative could be obtained between values every 15 min, or, if desired, a second derivative could be obtained from values every 30 min. the smae applies to my time series above. a 2nd derivative could be obtained between 1, 2 or n days. my point re `.diff(2).diff(2)` above was mentioned in the original post, therefore there would not be the need to post it elsewhere. care to explain your point in more detail?

Comment: No, look up [the definition of second derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_derivative). It's a mathematical concept that has nothing to do with increased lags.