# Lowpass filter to get second derivative of data from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (an excerpt is shown below):

```
    Time    head        hip_center  left_ankle
0   0.00    1916.654646 1487.842416 1152.102052
1   0.01    1916.800455 1487.870595 1152.110548
2   0.02    1916.913416 1487.934406 1152.113837
3   0.03    1916.992517 1488.334658 1152.083790
4   0.04    1917.109599 1488.298676 1152.239034
```

And what I want to do is calculate the acceleration of each column for each row, i.e. the second derivative. But I also need to apply a lowpass filter to filter out the noise.

I've defined the filter like so:

```
#Lowpass filter
from scipy.signal import butter, filtfilt

def butter_lowpass_filter(data, cutoff, fs, order):
    nyq = 0.5 * fs
    normal_cutoff = cutoff / nyq
    # Get the filter coefficients 
    b, a = butter(order, normal_cutoff, btype='low', analog=False)
    y = filtfilt(b, a, data.iloc[:, 1:])
    return y

#call function
butter_lowpass_filter(acc_filt, 8, 100, 2)
```

So what I want is for each column and each row, to get the second derivative with a filter applied to smooth it. I'm not so sure however at what stage do I calculate the derivative, and how? Because I did it originally with `.diff()` but this is what gives all the crazy noise to the results.

I want the output to also be in a dataframe. Any help on this?

**EDIT:** I know about the savgol filter, I will also be applying this, but I need to do a lowpass one as well independently.

**EDIT2:** This is the formula for the second derivative:

```
A(t) = (x(t+1) - 2 * x(t) + x(t-1)) / (SamplingPeriod * SamplingPeriod)
```

where Sampling Period is 0.01 secs.

Comment: So the derivative has to be computed between two rows? for instance: between time 0.00 and 0.01 for the two values in column head? (and then also for the other columns)

Comment: @DavideBrex Yes, indeed that's what i need

Comment: @DavideBrex I have added the formula for the second derivative, if that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59095333/13328010). They used `shift` to compute the second derivative:

```
df = df.set_index("Time")
for col in df:
    df[col+"_second_der"] = df[col] - 2*df[col].shift(1) + df[col].shift(2)
```

Output:

```
         head  hip_center  left_ankle  head_second_der  hip_center_second_der  left_ankle_second_der
Time                                                                                                
0.00  1916.65     1487.84     1152.10              NaN                    NaN                    NaN
0.01  1916.80     1487.87     1152.11              NaN                    NaN                    NaN
0.02  1916.91     1487.93     1152.11            -0.03                   0.04                  -0.01
0.03  1916.99     1488.33     1152.08            -0.03                   0.34                  -0.03
0.04  1917.11     1488.30     1152.24             0.04                  -0.44                   0.19
```

Let me know whether this works for you!

Comment: This is fine, thank you. But the question is also, at what point to I do this in regards to the filtering step? Do I filter then do deriv, or the opposite or filter before and after?

Comment: First you smooth the signal (low pass) and then compute the derivative. Do you want to do both in one go?