Function that recognizes the beginning of a slope change of a data vector that has noise
I need to process data from an experiment. The experiment was dropping a magnet through 2 coils, one in the beginning of the fall and one in the end, and measuring stuff based on the differences (as I repeated the process with varying height differences between the coils) and for that I need to identify the moment in which the interesting thing really happened and the moment the event ended and distinguish them from the noise that precedes/succeeds it. I uploaded the data here (there are several files there for the several sessions of the experiment). All of the data in all of the files are generally the same, plotting it as-is generates a sort of Gaussian/Lorentzian derivative form. In it there are three relevant columns: t is for time, X is the voltage data from the first coil, and Y is the voltage data from the second coil.
The raw data plot looks like this (minus the two red dots):

I'm looking for a way for me to automatically extract from the data the location of those two red dots. The plan originally was to derive the data twice, and the moment in which the second derivative is rising above zero or descending to zero are the two red dots from the graph I'm looking for. However, the data is not clean and has a lot of noise, so the second derivative is a mess and definitely not zero on the edges before the main event.
After trial and error this is the best I've managed to come up with. It does work for some of the Y vector but not for others and definitely not for X.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
import scipy
from scipy.signal import argrelmax
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter1d
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
from whittaker_eilers import WhittakerSmoother
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
def importData(filename):
  # use skiprows to skip the scope setup information and header
  # usecols column numbers starting from 0
  t, v1, v2 = np.loadtxt(filename, delimiter=',', skiprows=47, usecols=[1,2,3]).T
  return t, v1, v2

#%%

t,X,Y= importData(r"C:\Users\IMOE001\Desktop\inductance\15cm_10N.csv")
whittaker_smoother =WhittakerSmoother(lmbda=30, order=2, data_length=len(t))
nX=gaussian_filter1d(Y, 2, order=0)
nX=np.array(whittaker_smoother.smooth(nX))
dX= np.gradient(nX,t)
ndX=np.array(whittaker_smoother.smooth(dX))
ndX=gaussian_filter1d(ndX,2, order=0)
c1ndX=ndX/np.abs(np.mean(ndX))
c2ndX=(c1ndX-np.mean(c1ndX))/10000
ddX=np.gradient(c2ndX,t)
c1bex=ddX/np.abs(np.mean(ddX))
c2bex=(c1bex-np.mean(c1bex))/50000
bex=gaussian_filter1d(c2bex, 2, order=0)
bex=np.array(whittaker_smoother.smooth(bex))
plt.figure(dpi=500)



index_f=np.argmin(np.abs(bex[::-1])<5e-2)
index_i=np.argmin(np.abs(bex)<5e-2)
val_i=np.abs(np.mean(bex[:index_i]))*350
val_f=np.abs(np.mean(bex[len(bex)-index_f:]))*250
a= np.argmin(np.abs(bex)<val_i) 
b= len(bex)-np.argmin(np.abs(bex[::-1])<val_f)
print(a,b,index_i,index_f)

The above is built like this:

Preparation (import the data and needed functions) - lines 1-18

Smoothing the data using a Gaussian filter and Wittaker smoother filter (I admit I don't know how both filters actually work or what they are doing for the data, exept that the improved my results). Notice that the Wittaker smoother filter is using a library I found online and had to pip install it. - Lines 19-21

Derive the smoothed data using np.gradient and smoothing the results even more, this time divide and subtract the results with the mean of the results to have a closer to zero lines before and after the event. - Lines 22-25

Divide the results by 10000, as the magnitude of the derivative was super high around the event, and I only really care about the small rise at the beginning of the event and the descent to almost zero at the end of the event. - Line 26

Repeting the same process with the second derivative, but this time dividing it by 50000 for the same reason. - Lines 27-31

After getting a form of the second derivative that can be worked with, I extracted from it the index in which the second derivative first surpasses the number 0.05 and the index in which it lasts descends below that number. This is an arbitrary number that seemed the most fitting for one of the data vectors but apparently not for all of them. Those named index_i and index_f indicate being related to the initial tail and the final tail. - Lines 36-37

In an attempt to compensate to the mismatch of that arbitrary number to the other data vector I've attempted to use it as an index to average the tails of the second derivative, and search the indexes in which
it surpasses/descends beyond some multiplier of the respective average. The multiplier is, again, arbitrary (250 for the post-event tail, and 350 for the pre-event tail) and fits mostly to one specific data but not the rest. Those named a- is the start index and b- is the end index. - Lines 38-41

The code prints the a, b, index_i, index_f to help me see who is more accurate but none of them really are. Line 42



This is... a little incoherent, and cannot be meaningfully answered unless you embed sample data and graphs from your actual data. I encourage you to carefully read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

First let's ignore beginning of a slope change and I only really care about the small rise at the beginning of the event, and assume that you really do care about the outer inflection points. Simplify by using a more-standard filtfilt instead of a Whittaker:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import scipy.signal
from zipfile import ZipFile

data_list = []

archive = ZipFile('Data package from April 5th..zip')
for file_info in archive.infolist():
    set_df = pd.read_csv(
        filepath_or_buffer=archive.open(name=file_info.filename),
        skiprows=45, usecols=['Time(s)', 'Channel1', 'Channel2'],
        index_col='Time(s)',
    )

    # Convert to a series having a multi-index over experiment, time and channel
    set_df.columns.name = 'Channel'
    set_series = set_df.stack()
    set_series = pd.DataFrame({
        'Experiment': file_info.filename.removesuffix('.csv'),
        'Voltage': set_series,
    }).set_index('Experiment', append=True)['Voltage']
    set_series.index = (
        set_series.index
        .swaplevel('Experiment', 'Time(s)')
        .swaplevel('Channel', 'Time(s)')
    )
    data_list.append(set_series)
voltage = pd.concat(data_list)

# Used prior to differentials
filter_strength = 10
filter_b = np.full(shape=filter_strength, fill_value=1/filter_strength)

for experiment, egroup in voltage.groupby('Experiment'):
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.suptitle(experiment)

    # For each experiment, a figure having 2x2 axes: (volts, differential) by (channels 1, 2)
    ax_volts = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1), fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
    for col in ax_volts:
        col.tick_params('x', labelbottom=False)
    ax_diffs = (
        fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 3, sharex=ax_volts[0]),
        fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 4, sharex=ax_volts[1]),
    )
    for row, label in zip(
        (ax_volts, ax_diffs),
        ('Experimental data, volts', 'Second-order differential'),
    ):
        row[0].set_ylabel(label)

    cgroup: pd.Series
    for ax_volt, ax_diff, (channel, cgroup) in zip(
        ax_volts, ax_diffs, egroup.groupby('Channel'),
    ):
        filtered = pd.Series(scipy.signal.filtfilt(
            b=filter_b, a=1, x=cgroup,
        ))
        time = cgroup.index.get_level_values('Time(s)')
        ax_volt.plot(time, cgroup, label='Voltage')
        ax_volt.plot(time, filtered, label='Filtered')
        ax_volt.set_title(channel)

        # Finite-differences second-order differential: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59095333/313768
        diff2 = filtered - 2*filtered.shift(1) + filtered.shift(2)
        ax_diff.plot(time, diff2)

        '''
        Assumed structure:
        1. a positive peak
        2. 0 (inflection point A)
        3. minimum
        4. 0 (inflection point B)
        5. maximum
        6. 0 (inflection point C)
        7. a negative peak
        '''
        i_max = diff2.argmax()
        segc = diff2.iloc[i_max:]
        i_ipc = segc[segc < 0].index[0]
        segb = diff2.iloc[:i_max]
        i_ipb = segb[segb < 0].index[-1]
        sega = segb.iloc[:i_ipb]
        i_ipa = sega[sega > 0].index[-1]

        for ax, series in zip(
            (ax_volt, ax_diff), (cgroup, diff2)
        ):
            ax.scatter(
                time[[i_ipa, i_ipc]],
                series.iloc[[i_ipa, i_ipc]],
            )

    ax_volts[1].legend()

plt.show()


This correctly finds the inflection points for every dataset that you have. However, you've (vaguely) hinted that that's not what you actually care about. You seem to want some outer points at a smaller slope based on a tuning parameter that you've set to 10,000. That doesn't require a differential at all:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from zipfile import ZipFile

data_list = []

archive = ZipFile('Data package from April 5th..zip')
for file_info in archive.infolist():
    set_df = pd.read_csv(
        filepath_or_buffer=archive.open(name=file_info.filename),
        skiprows=45, usecols=['Time(s)', 'Channel1', 'Channel2'],
        index_col='Time(s)',
    )

    # Convert to a series having a multi-index over experiment, time and channel
    set_df.columns.name = 'Channel'
    set_series = set_df.stack()
    set_series = pd.DataFrame({
        'Experiment': file_info.filename.removesuffix('.csv'),
        'Voltage': set_series,
    }).set_index('Experiment', append=True)['Voltage']
    set_series.index = (
        set_series.index
        .swaplevel('Experiment', 'Time(s)')
        .swaplevel('Channel', 'Time(s)')
    )
    data_list.append(set_series)
voltage = pd.concat(data_list)

threshold = 0.1

for experiment, egroup in voltage.groupby('Experiment'):
    fig = plt.figure()
    fig.suptitle(experiment)

    # For each experiment, a figure having 1x2 axes: (channels 1, 2)
    ax_volts = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1), fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2)
    ax_volts[0].set_ylabel('Volts')

    cgroup: pd.Series
    for ax_volt, (channel, cgroup) in zip(
        ax_volts, egroup.groupby('Channel'),
    ):
        time = cgroup.index.get_level_values('Time(s)')
        ax_volt.plot(time, cgroup, label='Voltage')
        ax_volt.set_title(channel)

        iv_max = cgroup.argmax()
        iv_min = cgroup.argmin()
        v_thresh_hi = threshold*cgroup.iloc[iv_max]
        v_thresh_lo = threshold*cgroup.iloc[iv_min]
        i_hi = cgroup.iloc[:iv_max].searchsorted(v_thresh_hi)
        i_lo = cgroup.iloc[iv_min:].searchsorted(v_thresh_lo) + iv_min

        ax_volt.scatter(
            time[[i_hi, i_lo]],
            cgroup.iloc[[i_hi, i_lo]],
            c='red', label='threshold',
        )

    ax_volts[1].legend()

plt.show()



Thanks a lot for your help, but I need  to be a little bit more precise than the codes you've suggested. I'm sorry since appearently I wasen't clear at all with my intention, but I need to locate the momet that the magnet is starting to affect the data and the moment it stops to- I can't cut any part of the actuall relevant part. I've tried to make alteration to your codes to fit my criterion, but as it was probably ovioues  from my horrible attempt I dont really know how to code properly and I coulden't follow it to make the proper adjustment. Thanks again for your help
